Spikes appear during painting weight in Blender
I am still learning Blender(4.0.1).
I tried to make a separate hand for my character, but Blender cannot set weights automatically, so I decided to do it myself(which is surprisingly difficult). During painting, these spikes appear for some reason, they cannot be removed with a brush and weight set to 0. Sometimes I can find an angle where I can reduce them or even remove them!
I have already tried using Auto normalize, but it didn't help a lot.
My model is High poly because I don't like the idea of retopology and I think it is not worth my time while my PC can handle this model.
Here is a link with my model
How they look like:

